# HTML in NodeJS static folder can't load assets with relative path

Tags: node.js, express

I use a static folder for a NodeJS website, but strangely, in the index.html I still need to include a path to the folder that contains the files.

Adding the folder name to the path solves the problem, but only in the initial `index.html` page that is served. In any following pages (after clicking a hyperlink in the site), suddenly the folder name can **NOT** be part of the path!

FOLDER

```
dist
  └── viewer
   ├── index.html
   ├── test.html
   ├── style.css
   └── game.js
```

NODE

```
app.use(express.static('dist'))
app.get('/viewer', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/viewer/index.html')
})
```

INDEX.HTML

I can't load assets with `./` path, even though they're in the same folder

```
// WORKS
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./viewer/style.css">
// NOT WORKING
<script src="./game.js"></script>
```

TEST.HTML

If you click a link in `index.html` which leads to `test.html`, the behaviour is suddenly reversed!

```
// NOT WORKING
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./viewer/style.css">
// WORKS
<script src="./game.js"></script>
```

How can I get links to assets working normally across all pages in a node site?

Answer (score 0):

try using the exact path

`<script src="/viewer/game.js"></script>`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/viewer/style.css">`

You can check if your file is working in the browser

like opening

http://localhost/viewer/style.css

http://localhost/viewer/game.css

---

---

If you don't want to use the exact path then you have to set the correct path,
as `test.html` is inside `viewer` folder

**so in test.html you need to add**

`<script src="./game.js"></script>`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">`

---

---

In routing, you are accessing `index.html` in browser http://localhost/viewer

then the correct path of the sources would be as follows

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./viewer/style.css">
<script src="./viewer/game.js"></script>
```

as the route changes the directory to `/`.

if you are accessing `index.html` as http://localhost/viewer/index.html the correct path would be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
<script src="./game.js"></script>
```

---

---

In your case, you are confusing the router by using :

```
app.get('/viewer', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/viewer/index.html')
});
```

There is a file called `index.html`, when you enter a directory most server looks for `index.html` inside that directory. If available it just shows the `index.html` file.

You should not add route if a directory exists in a static folder.

---

---

**PS: It is best practice to use the exact path of the source.**

---

---

Hope this helps

Comment: This works, but if I use internal links in the HTML files, the directory suddenly has to be omitted! In my question, `index.html` links to `test.html`, and there the path has to be `src="/game.js"`. I would like consistent behaviour, because multiple pages are both in the `express get` routes as in internal links.

Comment: It is best practice to use the exact path of the source because of your stated behavior

Comment: Thanks for explaining, but I guess I just don’t understand why the html file can’t find the css file that’s right there in the same folder. What do you mean by “you are confusing the router” ?

Comment: I guess I just don't want this to happen : `as the route changes the directory to /`. Not sure why Node does this :)

Comment: You need to learn more about nodejs router. At first, it is a little complicated but it's awesome. :)